# Java CSV Writing

Tags: java, excel, csv

Im currently trying to write data into excel for a report. I can write data to the csv file however its not coming out in excel in the order I want. I need the data to print under best and worst fitness in each column instead of it all print under Average. Here is the relevant code, any help would be appreciated:

```
    String [] Fitness = "Average fitness#Worst fitness #Best Fitness".split("#");
    writer.writeNext(Fitness);

    //takes data from average fitness and stores as an int
    int aFit = myPop.individuals[25].getFitness();
    //converts int to string
    String aFit1 = Integer.toString(aFit);
    //converts string to string array
    String aFit2 [] = aFit1.split(" ");
    //writes to csv
    writer.writeNext(aFit2);
    //String [] nextCol = "#".split("#");



    int wFit = myPop.individuals[49].getFitness();
    String wFit1 = Integer.toString(wFit);
    String wFit2 [] = wFit1.split(" ");
    writer.writeNext(wFit2);

    int bFit = myPop.individuals[1].getFitness();
    String bFit1 = Integer.toString(bFit);
    String bFit2 [] = bFit1.split(" ");
    writer.writeNext(bFit2);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn0ZG.png)

Comment: Thanks guys, its all working now, the help is much appreciated.

Comment: remove your question then?

Comment: Ill remove you in a minute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should call your "writeNext" method once per line of datas:

```
String [] Fitness = "Average fitness#Worst fitness #Best Fitness".split("#");
writer.writeNext(Fitness);

int aFit = myPop.individuals[25].getFitness();
String aFit1 = Integer.toString(aFit);

int wFit = myPop.individuals[49].getFitness();
String wFit1 = Integer.toString(wFit);

int bFit = myPop.individuals[1].getFitness();
String bFit1 = Integer.toString(bFit);

writer.writeNext(new String[]{aFit1, wFit1, bFit1});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at
[CSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[])](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[]))

`public void writeNext(String[] nextLine)` 
- Writes the next line to the file.

The String array to provide is

> A string array with each comma-separated element as a separate entry.

You are writing 3 separate lines instead of 1 and each line you write contains an Array with a single entry.

```
writer.writeNext(aFit2);
writer.writeNext(wFit2);
writer.writeNext(bFit2);
```

**Solution:**
Create a single Array with all 3 entries (column values) and write that once on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using CSVWriter to write to a CSV file. Please make sure to mention as much details as possible in a question, it makes it much more readable to others.

As you can see from the documentation of CSVWriter:

> void  writeNext(String[] nextLine)
>
> Writes the next line to the file.

The writeNext method actually writes the array to the an individual line of the file. From your code:

```
writer.writeNext(aFit2);
writer.writeNext(wFit2);
writer.writeNext(bFit2);
```

So, instead of doing this  `String aFit2 [] = aFit1.split(" ");
Create an array of the values and then pass that array to **writeNext**

As an example, you can consider you own example of passing the array of column names, which gets written in a single line:

```
writer.writeNext(Fitness);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Apache Commons CSV

Here is the same kind of solution, but using the [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library. This library specifically supports the Microsoft Excel variant of CSV format, so you may find it particularly useful.

- [`CSVFormat.Predefined.EXCEL`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.Predefined.html#Excel)

Your data, both read and written in this example.

[image: Screenshot of seven rows of plain data in a CSV file, with three columns: Average, Worst, Best.]

The Commons CSV library can read the first row as header names.

Here is a complete example app in a single `.java` file. First the app reads from an existing `WorstBest.csv` data file:

```csv
Average,Worst,Best
10,5,15
11,5,16
10,6,16
11,6,15
10,5,16
10,5,16
10,4,16
```

Each row is represented as a `List` of three `String` objects, a `List< String >`. We add each row to a collection, a list of lists, a `List< List< String > >`.

Then we write out that imported data to another file. Each written file is name `WorstBest_xxx.csv` where `xxx` is the current moment in UTC.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class WorstBest {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        WorstBest app = new WorstBest();
        List < List < String > > data = app.read();
        app.write( data );
    }

    private List < List < String > > read ( ) {
        List < List < String > > listOfListsOfStrings = List.of();
        try {
            // Locate file to import and parse.
            Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/WorstBest.csv" );
            if ( Files.notExists( path ) ) {
                System.out.println( "ERROR - no file found for path: " + path + ". Message # 3cf416de-c33b-4c39-8507-5fbb72e113f2." );
            }

            // Hold data read from file.
            int initialCapacity = ( int ) Files.lines( path ).count();
            listOfListsOfStrings = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );

            // Read CSV file.
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader( path );
            Iterable < CSVRecord > records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse( reader );
            for ( CSVRecord record : records ) {
                // Average,Worst,Best
                // 10,5,15
                // 11,5,16
                String average = record.get( "Average" ); // Must use annoying zero-based index counting.
                String worst = record.get( "Worst" );
                String best = record.get( "Best" );

                // Collect
                listOfListsOfStrings.add( List.of( average , worst , best ) ); // For real work, you would define a class to hold these values. 
            }

        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listOfListsOfStrings;
    }

    private void write ( List < List < String > > listOfListsOfStrings ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( listOfListsOfStrings );
        // Determine file in which to write data.
        String when = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toString().replace( ":" , "•" ); // Colons are forbidden in names by some file systems such as HFS+.
        Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/WorstBest_" + when + ".csv" );
        // Loop collection of data (a list of lists of strings).
        try ( final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader( "Average" , "Worst" , "Best" ).print( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ; ) {
            for ( List < String > list : listOfListsOfStrings ) {
                printer.printRecord( list.get( 1 - 1 ) , list.get( 2 - 1 ) , list.get( 3 - 1 ) );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```